# Ansible Django Module Alternative Python Interpreter

Tags: python, django, ansible

I'm writing an ansible playbook for deploying a django app. As part of the process, I'd like to run the `staticcollect` command.

The issue I'm having is that the remote server has two python interpreters, one Python2.6 and one Python2.7, with Python2.6 being the default.

When I run the playbook, it runs using the Python2.6 interpretor and I need it to run against the Python2.7 interpretor.

Any idea on how this can be acheived?

My playbook is as follows:

```
- hosts: xxxxxxxxx
  vars:
    hg_branch:  dmv2
    django_dir: /opt/app/xxxx
    conf_file:  /opt/app/conf/xx_uwsgi.ini
    django_env:
        STATIC_ROOT: /opt/app/serve/static
  remote_user: xxxxxx
  tasks:
  - name: Update the hg repo
    command: chdir=/opt/app/xxxxx  hg pull -u --rev {{hg_branch}}
  - name: Collect static resources
    environment: django_env
    django_manage: command=collectstatic app_path={{django_dir}}
  - name: Restart the django service
    command: touch {{conf_file}}
  - name: check nginx is running
    service: name=nginx state=started
```

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/python` is just a symlink to either `/usr/bin/python2.6` or `/usr/bin/python2.7`. You can just invoke a bash command to update the symlink.

```
- name: Remove python --> python2.6 symlink
  sudo: yes
  command: rm /usr/bin/python

- name: Add python --> python2.7 symlink
  sudo: yes
  command: ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: You may want to confirm that python is located at `/usr/bin` by first typing `which python` on your particular instance image.

Comment: I had thought of doing this, however there are other services that require 2.6 to be the default alias. Is there a way of creating a user or session specific alias?

Comment: Invoking `alias python=/usr/bin/python2.7` works in my interactive terminal -- not sure about Ansible. If each Ansible command is executed in separate SSH session you will need to either invoke in each Ansible task (again) or perhaps add it to SSH options somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation at the day job and solved it with the ansible_python_interpreter host/group variable.

http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-python-pathing-not-having-a-python-2-x-in-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine

The cool part is that you can define a different path for python on a host by host basis if you really need to.